# AUCTeX can't find PDFLaTeX

Tags: emacs, auctex

I installed TeX Live 2011 from source in my Ubuntu. The AUCTeX module was also compiled and installed instead of pulling from Ubuntu's repository. However, when I opened a LaTeX file with Emacs, and compiled, it complained

> Running 'LaTeX' on 'jun13' with ``pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" jun13.tex''
>   /bin/sh: pdflatex: not found
>
> LaTeX exited abnormally with code 127 at Sat Oct 15 00:40:58

But PDFLaTeX was already in the PATH. I tried this file with TeXmaker, and it was successful. Could anyone please give me a hint what was going on? Thanks.

Comment: Does your ".emacs" file contain a nonexisting path to pdftex?

Comment: @keks Could you please explain more on "nonexisting path to pdftex"? My $HOME/.emacs only has two lines which are required by AUCTeX: (load "auctex.el" nil t t)
(load "preview-latex.el" nil t t)

Comment: OK, there's nothing to explain. What's the result of 'pdftex --version' on commandline? Maybe you've got a space in your path?

Comment: @keks Oh, it was "pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
kpathsea version 6.0.1
Copyright 2011 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.5.2; using libpng 1.5.2
Compiled with zlib 1.2.5; using zlib 1.2.5
Compiled with xpdf version 3.02pl5
"

Comment: So I guess the path was fine..

Comment: What about if you ask for `PATH` in a Emacs shell buffer? `M-x shell<return>` will open a shell, where you can ask for `echo $PATH`

Answer (score 4):

AUCTeX complains that `pdflatex` cannot be found. However, according to your comments you checked and found `pdftex`, not `pdflatex`, which still can be missing.

Today, `pdflatex` if often just a symbolic link to `pdftex`. For example, on my Ubuntu system with TeX Live 2011:

```
> ls -l `which pdflatex`
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 49 2011-10-07 22:13 /usr/local/bin/pdflatex
    -> /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex
> ls -l /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6 2009-08-15 19:49
    /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex -> pdftex
```

It finally points to `pdftex`.

So, you could

- configure Emacs/AUCTeX to run `pdftex` instead of `pdflatex`, since LaTeX is just the format, not the engine or executable
- or create a symbolic link, such as by

  ```
  ln -s /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/pdftex pdflatex
  ```

  in your path, where it can be found.
- or use the TeX Live Manager, start it by

  ```
  sudo tlmgr -gui
  ```

  and have a look in the menu *Actions*/ *Managing symbolic links* to the point *update symbolic links* or let it create symbolic links, this is also possible via command line option to `tlmgr` (see `tlmgr --help`).